# PostgreSQL: Column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql

I’m having an issue with a PHP application using PostgreSQL. I have a simple SQL statement that looks like this:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from "categories" where "promoter_id" = ? order by "sort_order" asc
```

But it triggers the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "categories.sort_order" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: ...om "categories" where "promoter_id" = $1 order by "sort_orde...
>   ^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "categories" where "promoter_id" = 7 order by "sort_order" asc)

The `sort_order` column contains arbitrary, unsigned integers that are used to “sort” records.

The above statement is issued by Eloquent (Laravel’s ORM) and seems to just be counting records in a table with a `WHERE` clause, so why is it triggering this error? I don’t really want to group the `sort order` column in case there are duplicate values (i.e. two records with a `sort_order` value of `2`) but that seems to be the solution the error message is suggestion.

Is there an alternative solution? I’m quite new to PostgreSQL so this seems to be a peculiarity that I’ve not faced with MySQL up to now.

Comment: Reason for down-vote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This is your query:

```
select count(*) as aggregate
from "categories"
where "promoter_id" = ?
order by "sort_order" asc;
```

What is the `order by` doing?  Why bother ordering when the result set has one row.  Just leave it out.

The specific reason why the error occurs is because the column `sort_order` is not in the result set, so Postgres cannot resolve it.  MySQL is much more flexible (and incorrect) about how it handles aggregation, so it allows constructs (such as this `order by`) which would cause an error in any other database.

Comment: The `order by` clause is added by an Eloquent global scope; I’m not manually adding it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't remove the ORDER BY, can you instead add an extra literal field:

```
SELECT count(*) AS aggregate, 0 AS sort_order
FROM "categories"
WHERE "promoter_id" = ?
ORDER BY "sort_order" asc;
```